# How do you properly bounce emacs installed via home-brew on macOS

Tags: osx, prelude

I just added a snippet to my ~/prelude/personal/personal.el
Time to activate it.
In the past I've found that brew services restart emacs doesn't work out.
So,

While inside the emacsclient, if I do

```
M-x kill-emacs
```

and then in my terminal do

```
$ brew services start emacs
```

I get

```
Service `emacs` already started, use `brew services restart emacs` to restart.
```

But I just killed emacs?  Whats going on, this is weird.

Comment: I assume these services don't work differently from a systemd unit to run an emacs daemon, so it might be starting again automatically. Just try running emacsclient once daemon had enough time to start up and become capable to handle clients.

Comment: If DoMiNeLa10 is correct, one way to check for this is to put a log string into your init file.  Something like `(message "%s: Emacs restarting" (current-time-string)) ' should add the restart time the *Messages* buffer.